# select2 how to add textbox and button in to combobox

Tags: css, jquery-select2

i am new to the select2. i just want to know how to add the textbox and button into the select2.
for better understanding i putting picture here that you might be clear about my question. any answer is appreciated. please help me .

[image: textbox and button is in select2 element]

html code..

```
<select style="width:100%"  multiple id="e8">
          <option value="volvo">Suger</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
<script>
   $("#e8").select2({
   placeholder: 'Placeholder  adding value test',
   minimumResultsForSearch: -1,    
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer which i got for this:

```
<select style="width:100%"  multiple id="e8">
          <option value="volvo">Suger</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
<script>
   $("#e8").select2({
   placeholder: 'Placeholder  adding value test',
   minimumResultsForSearch: -1,    
   });
  $(".select2-drop").append('<div><input type="text" style="width: 86%;
  padding: 9px;"name="lname"><input class="PrimaryBtn" type="submit" value="Add"></div>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this plugin, but you can try to create your own div with the textbox and button inside and append that div to `#select2-drop` div using `jQuery's .append()`. Don't know if `#select2-drop` div is always populated(just grabbed it from [plugin home page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/))

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean